# Add reference to script task in ssis

Tags: c#, ssis, reference

The way I understand it, SSIS script tasks can't use a reference unless it's in the GAC.

With this assumption:

- I've tried downloading the .net 2.0 sdk x64 (developing on 64 bit machine) that should have gacutil, still not there.
- I've tried installing the dll using a console app using the `System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish.GacInstall` method.  If it has installed it, I have no idea where becaues it's not in the available references in VS.

I can't copy it to assemblies because 'adminstrator rights' fails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is straight forward.

to use 'gacutil' in the .net 2.0 sdk ([located here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1AEF6FCE-6E06-4B66-AFE4-9AAD3C835D3D&displaylang=en)) you have to open the sdk command prompt AND 'as administrator'

[alt text http://myofficevideos.com/pics/screen.png](http://myofficevideos.com/pics/screen.png)

[alt text http://myofficevideos.com/pics/capture.png](http://myofficevideos.com/pics/capture.png)

Comment: I think the best way to get an answer to a question is to ask it on a forum and then all of the sudden it comes to you. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87fa2c45-b0dc-4bf1-b1bc-4206d394b1f1/where-can-i-find-gacutil-for-a-64bit-machine?forum=netfxsetup) I Found GacUtils in the following folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools"

I could then open command prompt (in adminisrator mode) and navigate to the folder containing gacutils:

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

and then run my command to install using gacutils:

gacutil -I "C:\myDll.dll"